# Can't connect to couchbase via php

Tags: php, zend-framework, couchbase, php-extension

I have this strange issue that I'm banging my heads off. It works on dev machine but when I moved it to prod machine, I got this error:

```
FastCGI-stderr: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CouchbaseLibcouchbaseException' with message 'Failed to create libcouchbase instance: Administrator account must not be used to access the data in the bucket' in /var/www/myapps/Bootstrap.php:149
```

This is line 149:

```
$couchbase = new Couchbase($db['host'],$db['username'],$db['password'], $db['dbname']);
```

Did I miss something? I turn off all my firewall and selinux to make sure it's not their issue. Still the same..

I'm using:

```
CentOS 6.4 64Bit
Couchbase 2.01
whatever the php-ext-couchbase define in this repo:
http://packages.couchbase.com/rpm/couchbase-centos62-x86_64.repo
```

I can login with no issue via browser with the same username and password.

The question is, is this really an account issue? If it is then how or where do I create another user? Can't seem to find it anywhere in the documentation.

If not, any suggestion on how I should debug this? Please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your bucket password protected? If not, just pass a blank user id and password to the connect. To find out if it has a password go to the bucket configuration area (Data Buckets, Click the down arrow, click the "edit" button). The password is set under "access control"
on the edit screen.

Comment: Thanks @Don Dickinson.  It's password protected and I put in the username and password in my php apps setting to try to attach to the data bucket and no luck.  The strangest thing is, it works on my dev machine but not on production machine.  I'm suspecting the php-ext-couchbase version that's the culprit but wasn't quite sure since I don't know which version the pecl install couchbase script installed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction @Don Dickinson.  Your advise solved my problem.  I was using the old assumption like MySQL where if you have username password to manage the db, then that username and password can/will be used to connect to db.  I didn't know that one can actually connect directly to the bucket without username and password which is very SCARY...  So I added the password to the bucket, remove the username in my application and put in the password for the bucket and voila, it works.  Many thanks again for your help.  :-)

Comment: Don't use accounts with admin permissions to perform data transactions. Either pass NULL as the username or name of the bucket.